# Designing an A/B experiment where members can drop out

Tags: experiment-design

Sorry for being a bit vague here, but I have an A/B experiment design question that I can't figure out

Suppose I have a treatment that I want to apply to a group over a month or so, but have the following constraints:

1. Once a member is in the group, the treatment has to be applied until the either the period ends or the member withdraws from the service
2. Calculating eligibility for the treatment is a somewhat expensive process, but can be done
3. A new member having the treatment applied to them halfway through their time using the service is possible

So my main question is this: is it better to start with a group of candidates before the test begins and then try compare the results at the end of the treatment period when the # of participants is not the same as when it started or would it be better to keep the # of participants relatively constant, even though the amount of time each participant is in the experiment is variable?

Answer (score 3):

Intuitively:

1. A member's withdrawing from the service, is not unrelated to the effect of the treatment.
2. The effect of the treatment depends on the treatment period.

(Although, without knowing the specifics of the case, this can't be said with certainty.)

Your first course, where the groups are determined before the period's start, and evaluated at the period's end, is better at point 2 than the second course. Note that, due to 1., you should probably not discard users who left the service during treatment. These could be counted either as treatment failures, or as as a separate category of dropping out during treatment.